# Read a line from text file and delete it

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi

I want to read a text file line by line, perform some checks, and if the line is not required, delete it.
I have done the code for reading line, but I don't know how to delete that line if it is not required by me.
Please help me find the simplest method for deleting the line.
Here is my code snippet what I tried:

```
   char ip[32];
   int port;
   DWORD dwWritten;
   FILE *fpOriginal, *fpOutput;
   HANDLE hFile,tempFile;
   hFile=CreateFile("Hell.txt",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
   tempFile=CreateFile("temp.txt",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
   WriteFile(hFile,"10.0.1.25 524192\r\n\r\n10.0.1.25 524193\r\n\r\n",strlen("10.0.1.25 524192\r\n\r\n10.0.1.25 524193\r\n\r\n"),&dwWritten,0);
   fpOriginal = fopen("Hell.txt", "r+");
   fpOutput = fopen("temp.txt", "w+");

   while (fscanf(fpOriginal, " %s %d", ip, &port) > 0) 
      {
         printf("\nLine1:");
         printf("ip: %s, port: %d", ip, port);
         char portbuff[32], space[]=" ";
         sprintf(portbuff, "%i",port);
         strcat(ip," ");
         strcat(ip,portbuff);
         if(port == 524192)
            printf("\n Delete this Line now");
         else
            WriteFile(tempFile,ip,strlen(ip),&dwWritten,0);
      }

     fclose(fpOriginal);
     fclose(fpOutput);
     CloseHandle(hFile);
     CloseHandle(tempFile);
     remove("Hell.txt");
     if(!(rename("temp.txt","Bye.txt")))
     {
         printf("\ncould not rename\n");
     }
     else 
        printf("\nRename Done\n");
     //remove ("Hell.txt");
```

Comment: Read the whole file into memory and write out all but the line you want to delete.

Comment: looks complex :( can you give some example?

Comment: may be you can try `r+` mode where you can read as well as write to the file

Comment: You shouldn't mix `Win32` and `C`-stdlib if possible. `Win32` offers `ReadFile` and is more consistent than using `fopen`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's an example:

```
char* inFileName = "test.txt";
char* outFileName = "tmp.txt";
FILE* inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r");
FILE* outFile = fopen(outFileName, "w+");
char line [1024]; // maybe you have to user better value here
int lineCount = 0;

if( inFile == NULL )
{
    printf("Open Error");
}

while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), inFile) != NULL )
{
    if( ( lineCount % 2 ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf(outFile, "%s", line);
    }

    lineCount++;
}


fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);

// possible you have to remove old file here before
if( !rename(inFileName, outFileName) )
{
    printf("Rename Error");
}
```

Comment: I did the same but still the file was neither deleted nor renamed, even when the function rename() succeeded. Could it be an issue due to the attributes I used while using CreateFile().

Comment: Does the `rename()` (or `delete()`) function return an error or is an `errno` set?

Comment: No, no errors are returned. I see two strange behaviours here.
1. Placing remove() before rename() gives an error while rename()ing the file.
2. Placing remove() after rename() does not rename the file but generates a new file :\

Comment: And now another issue, sometimes, rename() fails as well, once in twenty tries.

Comment: I updated my Question and added the latest code that I am trying.

Comment: If rename fails, check the *errno*. you can see the errnos set by this function here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename - this will give you more information about *why* it failed.

Comment: Also you can try a `sleep()` call between rename and remove. Take a look at that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021639/overwriting-files-in-windows-by-renaming-randomly-fails

Answer (score 1):

There are many to solve this problem one of them is, you can open another file for writing when you reach at a point where you don't want to write omit that paint and continue writing until end of file. Latterly you can delete old file and rename new file with old one.

```
if(number == 2)
{
     continue;
}
else
{
    writetofilefunction()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all line wich does not contain the number 2 into a new file and then use the new file instead the old file

```
fp = fopen("File.txt", "r");
fp2 = fopen("File_copy.txt", "w");
while (fscanf(fp, " %s %d", string, &number) > 0) {
        if(number != 2)
        {
             fprintf(fp2, "%s %d\n", string, number);
        }
}
close(fp);
close(fp2);
remove("File.txt");
rename( "File_copy.txt", "File.txt" );
```

Comment: I did the same but still the file was neither deleted nor renamed, however the function rename() succeeded. Could it be an issue due to the attributes I used while using CreateFile().

Comment: it could be access privilege problem. check the returned values of remove and rename

Comment: does the "File_copy.txt" file created ?

Comment: Yes file is created. I see two strange behaviours here.
1. Placing remove() before rename() gives an error while rename()ing the file.
2. Placing remove() after rename() does not rename the file but generates a new file :\

Comment: And now another issue, sometimes, rename() fails as well, once in twenty tries.

Comment: I updated my Question and added the latest code that I am trying.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan the problem looks like a synchronization problem. In linux we use sync()/fsync() for synchronization before the remove and the rename. for windows there is FlushFileBuffer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to do it? :(
My task is so simple, Rename a file and delete the original file :(

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to write back to the same file (write back what you read out except for the lines you don't want) and use the Windows API function `SetEndOfFile` to truncate it when finished. This will probably be a bit messier to code but you won't need to create a second copy of the file so it's more efficient from a disk usage standpoint.