# Updating and deleting contents of a file

Tags: c, string, file, file-io

I have a file named as Empdata.txt having fields as "(%s)id,(%s)name,(%d)salary". Firstly, i am inserting some values to it. Now i want to update record having the same id as given by the user. I am using this code:

```
struct employee
{
    char id[100];
    char name[100];
    int sal;
};
int main()
{
FILE *ptr;
struct employee e;
ptr=fopen("Empdata.txt","w+");
printf("Enter Employee id");
scanf("%s",id);
while(!feof(ptr))
{
    fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,ptr);
    if(strcmp(id,e.id)==0)
    {
        printf("Enter name");
        scanf("%s",e.name);
        printf("Enter basic salary");
        scanf("%d",&e.sal);
        fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,ptr);
    }
};
fclose(ptr);
}
```

But it is not matching the ids. So it is not updating even. Further i have to perform delete operation also. I am not getting how to delete record having a particular id.
Please assume all variables are initialized properly.

Comment: Try to indent your code in future questions. It makes reading code 100x easier.

Comment: You are not reading anything from your file. You just open it, then (incorrectly) check for eof a few times, then close it. Might as well just not have any file at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a line from text file and delete it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758678/read-a-line-from-text-file-and-delete-it)

Comment: @n.m. then in which mode should we open a file in order to update it ??

Comment: How many modes are there? What does the documentation for `fopen` say about each of them?

Comment: @n.m m very new to C. I have started learning 3days ago. So i have pretty less khnowledge of C.

Comment: After last edit: now you are *reading* from a *write-only* file!

Comment: I'm not trying to check your knowledge, I'm showing you where to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to update a record, you will have to both read, and write records.  Hence the "w" file mode is insufficient (ie:`fopen("Empdata.txt","w");`).  Perhaps the `"r+"` mode would be more appropriate?

First thing in your `while()` loop, you need to read a record from your file.
At the bottom of the loop, you need to note your file position (ie:`ftell()`), so that if the next record is a match, you will know where to `fseek()` back to in order to write the updated record back to the file.

```
long position=0;

...

while(!feof(ptr))
{
    fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,ptr);
    if(strcmp(id,e.id)==0)
    {
    ...
    }

    position=ftell(ptr);    
};
```

If you find a matching record (ie:`if(strcmp(id,e.id)==0)`),  the very last thing you should do is re-position to the beginning of the matching record (ie:`fseek()`) and then write the updated record.  And since you have accomplished your task, you should break out of the while loop and return.

```
{
...
fseek(ptr, position, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,ptr);
}
```

Comment: for example we have to update the data of id "EMP_3" then how to set pointer position at fseek ? Can u please explain it by writing code of an example.

Comment: it worked.. Thanks.. I have just 1 more ques, if we want to delete this record then after reading and comparing, how we should delete it ? Will fseek play any role in it ? if yes then how .

Comment: user3578083, yes.  It is quite likely that  fseek() would play a role in deleting a record.  You asked how this might be accomplished; and perhaps that is another question?