# How to remove specific line in text file using C programming language

Tags: c, file, delete-row

I want delete that line in text file after i search of it :

eg:

```
char *id;   //id to search
char buf[1024];

FILE *fp=fopen("abc.txt","r");

while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp)!=NULL)
{
   if(strstr(buf,id)!=NULL)

       {printf("%s\n",buf); }

}
```

Comment: Why you want to delete in _that_ file itself? Why can't you create a new file with the lines you need?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15759017/3970360) might be useful for your situtation.

Comment: Your code looks almost fine as it is.  What's wrong with it?  Does it not do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the file there are basically two solutions:

1. For a moderately small file you could read the whole file into memory. Recreate the file and write it out, except the line you want to remove.
2. Read, line by line, from the original file. Write all lines except the one you want to remove to a new temporary file. Rename the temporary file as the original file. File-size doesn't matter here (other than for speed).

Method 1 has a big drawback: If there is an error (bug in your code, system goes down, or other problem) the contents might not all be written and you could lose data. Method 1 is usually quicker though, and it allows you to make many kind of transformations of the data in a simple way.